# display black screen from going one activity to another activity for few mins

Tags: android

I have a login page from login, if the user clicks the login button, it will go to tabactivity. In tab activity I have four tabs: home,stock etc. From tabactivity I am calling activity group for nested activity. From activity group I am calling homeactivity. From home I am loading tab bar and calling webservices and parsing value and load the home activity in home tab. It takes time. How do I avoid black screen? Can anybody give an example? I have tried a lot but it's not working. If anyody knows, please give code.
In second activity I am loading tab bar up to tab loaded and calling webservices. I have to show some splash screen.

I am adding tabbar in `doInBackground` method, is it correct?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

//import com.inquest.LoginActivity.FetchTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
//TabActivity 

public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity 
{
     int width =40;  
     int height =49;
    //private TabHost tabHost;
    TextView txthome;
    TextView txtstock;
    TextView txtcitn;
    TextView txtmyquest;
    Button btn;
    //private ProgressDialog pd = null; 
    private ProgressDialog dlg; 
    private Object data = null; 
    String strusername="";
    String strPassWord="";
    String questGroupId="";
    String userid="";
    String systemuserid="";
    String providerid="";
    private ProgressDialog dialog; 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
       setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab); 






    new TabTask(HelloTabWidget.this).execute(null);

 //}

 }





 public class TabTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> 
 { 
        private ProgressDialog dlg; 
          private Context ctx; 
        public TabTask(Context context) { 
            ctx = context; 
        } 




        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute(); 
            dlg = new ProgressDialog(HelloTabWidget.this); 
            dlg.setMessage("Loading...."); 
            dlg.show();
        } 



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                 TabHost.TabSpec spec;
                 TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
                 TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
                Resources res = getResources();

                                                    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"verdanab.TTF");
                Typeface myTypeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"verdana.TTF");
                Intent homeintent;   
                // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused) 
                homeintent = new Intent();
                 Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
                 String strusername=bundle.get("strUserName").toString();
                 String strPassWord=bundle.get("strPassword").toString();
                 String questGroupId=bundle.get("questGroupId").toString();
                 String userid=bundle.get("userid").toString();
                 String systemuserid=bundle.get("systemuserid").toString();
                 String providerid=bundle.get("providerid").toString();
                  Log.d("home activity username", strusername);
                 Log.d("home activity password", strPassWord);
                 Log.d("home activityquestGroupId",questGroupId);
                    homeintent.setClass(ctx, HomeActivityGroup.class); 
                  homeintent.putExtra("strUserName", strusername);
                  homeintent.putExtra("strPassWord",strPassWord );
                  homeintent.putExtra("questGroupId",questGroupId);
                  homeintent.putExtra("userid",userid);
                  homeintent.putExtra("systemuserid", systemuserid);
                  homeintent.putExtra("checking", "one");

                   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home_tab_bar_icon)).setContent(homeintent);
                tabHost.addTab(spec); 

                //homeintent = new Intent().setClass(this,ThemeSearchActivity.class); 
                homeintent = new Intent().setClass(ctx,StockActivity.class);
                homeintent.putExtra("strUserName", strusername);
                homeintent.putExtra("strPassWord",strPassWord );
                homeintent.putExtra("questGroupId",questGroupId);
                homeintent.putExtra("userid",userid);
                homeintent.putExtra("systemuserid", systemuserid);
                homeintent.putExtra("providerid", providerid);  
                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("stock").setIndicator("Stock",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.stocks_tab_bar_icon)).setContent(homeintent);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);
                homeintent = new Intent().setClass(ctx,ArticleActivity.class); 
                   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("citn").setIndicator("CITN",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.citn_tabbar_icon)).setContent(homeintent);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);
                homeintent = new Intent().setClass(ctx, MyCompaniesActivity.class); 
                spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("myquest").setIndicator("My Quest",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.quest_tab_bar_icon)).setContent(homeintent);
                tabHost.addTab(spec);

                for (int i =0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
                     //tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                      tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = height;
               tabWidget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = width;
               RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout)tabWidget.getChildAt(i); 
               TextView tv = (TextView)relLayout.getChildAt(1); 
               tv.setTextSize(10.0f);
               //tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 1, 0, 0);
              tv.setTypeface(myTypeface1);          



            }
            }
                catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }   


}
```

Comment: you can call web service in different thread and use progress bar to avoid black screen.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the  [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  functionality in your Tabbar activity.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // perform long running operation operation
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
     }
}
```

Comment: In second activity I am calling activity group from activity group I am calling another activity .in second activity calling webservices

Answer (score 1):

I am also having same problem but my problem is solved by adding this attribute to the activity:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar")]
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple just don't call any long running tasks within onCreate() method it blocks your activity creation till the task completed.

Just defines the UI tasks under this method and calls any other call from onStart() or onResume() methods.

Try to keep your oncreate() method lite as much as possible.